# laravel 5.6 with guzzlehttp 6 trying to get property of a title of a non object

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-5.6

i was trying to consume an external api. https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json,
and below is my controller code.

```
public function listMovies()
    {
        $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://yts.am/api/v2/',
        ]);

        $response = $client->request('GET', 'list_movies.json');
        //dd($response);

        $movies = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        return view('movies.index', compact('movies'));
    }
```

and this is my view file

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row py-5">
            <div class="col">
            @foreach($movies as $movie)
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{$movie->title }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{ $movie->summary }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but iam getting this error: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View:

Comment: You'd better check the content of $movies in the controller, because the response might not be what you expect.

Comment: Is `$movie` an array? Try `$movie['title']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `$movies` object don't have property `title` and `summary`, but you can access it like this:

```
 @foreach($movies->data->movies as $movie)
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{$movie->title }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ $movie->summary }}
                </div>
            </div>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Is it work for you? or you still can't access that properties?

Comment: @Rainmax93 no it doesnot work yet, when i dd($movies) i get this response {#475 ▼
  +"status": "ok"
  +"status_message": "Query was successful"
  +"data": {#476 ▼
    +"movie_count": 8110
    +"limit": 20
    +"page_number": 1
    +"movies": array:20 [▼
      0 => {#477 ▶}
      1 => {#480 ▶}
      2 => {#482 ▶}
      3 => {#485 ▶}
      4 => {#488 ▶}

Comment: try `dd($movies->data->movies)`

Comment: so where does data property is coming from?